# Convert string "DDMMMYYYY:HH:MM:SS" to date format

Tags: r, datetime

I have imported a sas file with date ion the format `21JAN1988:00:00:00` seen as factor in R.

I want to convert this into an r date format `1988-01-21`.

How do I go about this?

Comment: Try `anytime::anydate("21JAN1988:00:00:00")`

Comment: works perfectly. Thank you @zx8754

Answer (score 2):

Using *as.Date*:

```
x <- "21JAN1988:00:00:00"
as.Date(x, format = "%d%b%Y")  
# [1] "1988-01-21"
```

Using anytime package:

```
anytime::anydate(x)
# [1] "1988-01-21"
anytime::anytime(x)
# [1] "1988-01-21 01:00:00 GMT"
```

---

**Note:** There must be a duplicate for this post, but I couldn't find. Let me know in the comments if you find one, I will convert this post to community wiki.